# Home server, NAS, Privacy and Web hosting

Tags: server, cloud, storage, hosting, nas

new here and to everything related to home servers but I have a question that I hope I can get some help with.

Here’s what I would like to do, apologies in advance for my very beginner understanding:

- I would like to set up personal storage at home connected to the internet (I believe like NAS). This would have all my media, photos, music, documents etc.
- I would like to access this from anywhere with an internet connection, and be able to upload my photos and anything else on my phone and laptop.
- I would like it to obviously have security and encryption so that my information is secure and not publicly available.
- I would also like to host my own site and domain on at home on this unit. (I can get a static IP and domain if needed)
- I would like to set up my email through this site at home as well

I basically want to have ownership over my data and info. I don’t want to use google for my email. Don’t want Instagram for my photos and don’t want to use the cloud whether it’s Dropbox or iCloud or google photos. I want everything to be on my unit at home connected securely to the internet.

Currently I don’t care about gaming or using this to steam media on my local network or over the internet, even though eventually it would be nice.

Can someone please help me and tell me what on earth am I taking about and what am I trying to do here. What is this called and where should I start.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a Synology.

The system has an app that will backup your photos on your phone, a backup app for your computer and similar tools to google.
You can create docs and sheets. It is all hosted locally on your system and can be configured for anywhere access.

Comment: Can I also host my site on this and have an email running form this synology?

Comment: yes you can install wordpress onto the device and run a mail sever.